# Multiple JSON objects and get array in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have problem in parsing JSON.
http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cdWQqIXQfC?indent=2
Actually i want to get the below

```
"jean": {
          "color": "red", 
          "cost": 15000, 
          "size": 28
        }
```

to get from URL . then need to set listview. But first i didnt get json array itself.\
The below code throws exception and shows no value for men.

I tried using

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String firstname = null;
    String lastname = null;
    String username = null;
    String username1 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
    }

    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
        String yourJsonStringUrl = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cdWQqIXQfC?indent=2";
        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;
        JSONObject dataJsonArry = null;
        JSONObject dataJsonArry1 = null;
        JSONObject dataJsonArry2 = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);
                dataJsonArry = json.getJSONObject("online");
                dataJsonArry1 = json.getJSONObject("men");
                dataJsonArry2 = json.getJSONObject("clothes");
                dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("jean");
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    lastname = c.getString("cost");
                    username = c.getString("size");
                    Log.e("Hello", "firstname: " + firstname + ", lastname: "
                            + lastname + ", username: " + username + "star:"
                            + username1);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
        }
    }
}
```

json parser:

```
public class JsonParser {

    final String TAG = "JsonParser.java";

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

I dont know how to acheive this ... Can anyone help me ...

Comment: `jean` is a `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
try { 
            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);
            JSONObject onlineJsonObj = json.getJSONObject("online");
            JSONObject menJsonObj = online.getJSONObject("men");
            JSONObject clothesJsonObj= menJsonObj.getJSONObject("clothes");
            JSONObject jeanJsonObj= clothesJsonObj.getJSONObject("jean");

                lastname = clothesJsonObj.getString("cost");
                username = clothesJsonObj.getString("size");
                Log.e("Hello", "firstname: " + firstname + ", lastname: "
                        + lastname + ", username: " + username + "star:"
                        + username1);
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null; 
    }
```

There is no JSONArray in you respose. JsonArray is between '['and ']' brackets.

Comment: hi, I just changed my code for array values , but it shows to exception ... do u hav idea? 
like this `JSONObject clothesJsonObj = menJsonObj.getJSONObject("clothes");
                dataJsonArr = clothesJsonObj.getJSONArray("jean");
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    size = c.getString("size");
                    color = c.getString("color");
                    cost = c.getString("cost");`

Comment: Again  there is no array exists in your Json response. Then why are you still using jsonArray. All the response is in the form of objects. Have you tried the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Jean is a `JSONObject` and you use `JSONArray` in your code. Moreover `size` and `cost` are numbers but you use `getString()`. So this code should work (please use relevant name for your variables : do not store a cost in a variable called lastname)

```
JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);
JSONObject dataJsonOnline = json.getJSONObject("online");
JSONObject dataJsonMen = dataJsonOnline.getJSONObject("men");
JSONObject dataJsonCloth = dataJsonMen.getJSONObject("clothes");
JSONObject dataJsonJean = dataJsonCloth.getJSONObject("jean");

String color = dataJsonJean.getString("color");
int cost  = dataJsonJean.getInt("cost");
int size = dataJsonJean.getString("size");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand your comment. From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) the methods are `String getString(String)` or `ìnt getInt(String)`. `getString(int)` does not exist.